# Modify category archive page loop on functions.php

Tags: php, functions, loop, ajax, archive-template

I was able to modify the query on the category archive page using

`global $wp_query;
   $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'terms' => 20),
    )
    ));
query_posts($args)`

My problem starts when I'm trying to get these posts through Ajax. There is a dropdown which shows a list of locations and when a user clicks on one of those locations, the posts under the dropdown change depending on the choice. I moved the entire loop together with the code above to functions.php to do this.

But a counter that I've put shows that no posts are being loaded according to the change in the loop for the taxonomy 'location' that I specified here. I even set the value as 20 since I know the location taxonomy `20` has posts linked to it. I do the Ajax loading of posts on other pages so I'm pretty sure the Ajax calls and requests are working fine too but what I think is the problem here is that the functions.php does not understand the `global $wp_query;` that I've specified here above the loop.

Is my understanding correct and if it is, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Don't use query_posts. Use WP_Query and pre_get_posts

Comment: I usually write a new WP_Query in the functions.php to do this but in this case, wouldn't it affect the default archive page loop?

Comment: Do you need to add a taxonomy term to your category page. And **never ever** use `query_posts`, it breaks the `$wp_query` global which holds the main query object. This also breaks pagination

Comment: I had segregated by the custom post type on the archive page using `if( $post->post_type == 'cars' && $post->post_type == has_term(20,'location'))`. Now when I move this to functions.php, its not working.

Comment: Since I'm sending the data to a function which does not tie into `pre_get_posts` the function has no idea which query it needs to modify. @Pieter Goosen

Comment: If you this type of sorting, you would be better of using `usort` on the `the_posts` filter. I have done a few posts on this subject. I cannot unfortunately post an exact solution as I'm getting ready to go to the rugby this afternoon. If you don't come right, I will try to look into this tommorow

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen. I've never used `usort` before but I will read up on it and try and figure this out.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I looked up `usort` but I didn't understand how it would help. My issue is that my functions.php can't access the query in my custom function since it does not tie into `pre_get_posts`. Any other way other than writing a new WP_Query?